# Web UI for inputting a function from the reals to the reals, such as a probability distribution

Tags: javascript, user-interface, math, wolfram-mathematica

I would like a web interface for a user to describe a one-dimensional real-valued function.  I'm imagining the user being presented with a blank pair of axes and they can click anywhere to create points that are thick and draggable.  Double-clicking a point, let's say, makes it disappear.  The actual function should be shown in real time as an interpolation of the user-supplied points.

Here's what this looks like implemented in Mathematica (though of course I'm looking for something in javascript):

[image]
<sub>(source: [yootles.com](http://yootles.com/outbox/locator.png))</sub>

Comment: Why, if you have Mathematica, would you use Javascript ?  Why not use Web Mathematica ?

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought about Web Mathematica.  I assume it has a bunch of obnoxious licensing restrictions and wouldn't yield something as slick as a pure javascript solution.  If your experience is contrary to that, I'd love to hear about it.  Maybe make it an actual answer?

Answer (score 2):

If your website users install the new CDF player plugin, they will be able to work with the above example you coded!!

While I have no experience with this yet, I believe the CDF file code drops directly into your page and will load automatically with the correct MIME type enabled.

Here is an example of a live manipulatable interface embedded in a blog post: [Mathematica: Interactive mathematics in the web browser](http://www.walkingrandomly.com/?p=3267).

Cool, huh?

Comment: Thanks! Note that CDF here is "Computable Document Format", not to be confused with Cumulative Distribution Function.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that a probability distribution has to be monotonically non-decreasing over its entire run, which your example is not. Even worse, that small dip is not due to user error -- their points are increasing as required -- but is an artifact of the interpolation method. If you use linear interpolation, then any non-monotonicity is your user's fault, and you can warn them.

Comment: Good point about linear interpolation.  I might even want to interpolate such that the resulting function was always monotone regardless of where the user placed the points.  In any case, the choice of how to interpolate should be the easy part of this...

Comment: Wtf ? It only has to be non negative, unless you're talking cumulative distribution functions (and I think OP is not). But it is true that spline interpolation can yield negative values, that you may want to cap to zero. Another good solution is to spline the log density instead.

Comment: There are also ways to spline monotonically (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation ) in case the OP was actually wanting a CDF and not a density function.

Answer (score 0):

The [Distribution Builder](http://www.dangoldstein.com/dsn/archives/2006/01/what_will_the_r_1.html) tool by Dan Goldstein has an alternative interface for eliciting probability distributions.